# OpenGL app crashes immediately on start up

Tags: c++, opengl, codeblocks

This is my main function:

```
int main(int argc,char * args[])
{
    printf("working");
    glutInit(&argc,args);
    startup();
    glutDisplayFunc(render);
    glutKeyboardFunc(handle_keys);
    glutTimerFunc(1000 / fps,mainloop,0);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

"working" never gets printed to the console.

I had printf and all the other stuff working perfectly a while ago and now it crashes before anything is called. I don't know where to look for a bug. FYI I am working with code::blocks and am using multiple source files which I am new to. This (all source files) compiles without an error.

Comment: Do you have any globals?

Comment: 1. Use a debugger. 2. Add `\n` in the end of each line you print, unless you have a specific reason not to.

Comment: @Simple Yes in another file but I haven't Changed them since the last successful build

Comment: Also use `fprintf(stderr, …)` so that things don't need to be flushed.

Comment: What have you changed "a while ago"? Are you sure you have all the needed libraries in your PATH?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that all globals are initialized before main(). The crash may be there.